# Ruby on Rails where clause with two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have three models:

Artist, Album, Track

Each track has an album_id and each album has an artist_id

I want to find all tracks for a specific artist, something like the following:

```
select track.* from  tracks, albums where track.albmum_id==album.id and album.artist_id=5;
```

So I am hoping to end up with tracks that I can then paginate over.

My best effort so far is this but it is not working:

```
@tracks = Track.joins(:albums).select("track.*").where(artist_id: @artist.id).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I get: ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'albums' was not found on Track; perhaps you misspelled it?)
I am using Rails 4.0.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define "not working." Do you receive an error? What error? Also, which version of Rails?

Comment: Did you put the relationship between the models ? With `has_many` and `belong_to` ?

Comment: I added the error and the version, and yes, I am using has_many and belongs_to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a relashionship like this:

```
class Artist
  has_many :tracks, :through => :albums
```

Then, you can use:

```
a = Artist.first
a.tracks
```

With the `has_many through`, the query is automatically built for you.